# PHP - Not producing proper array for line graph

Tags: php, arrays

I have a script to produce some data that gets pulled into a line graph. I need to produce one line per each company which goes with the `$teamCount` variable. Right now the script is only creating one array and sticking all of the lines for each company within a single array, which essentially is creating year over year data (which it shouldn't).

I'm unsure how to do this whether I nest a `foreach` or another `for` loop.

Here is the script:

```
      $finance = array(
        array(
            'key' => $companyName,
            'values' => array()
        )
      );

      for ($i = 0; $i < $teamCount; ++$i) {                 
          $count = $i + 1;
          $companyName = 'Company ' . $count;
          $finance[0]['values'][] = array('x' => $count, 'y' => 25000000);
        }

        $insertdata['finance'] = $finance;
```

Here is the data output:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'key' => 'Company 2',
    'values' => 
    array (
      0 => 
      array (
        'x' => 1,
        'y' => 25000000,
      ),
      1 => 
      array (
        'x' => 2,
        'y' => 25000000,
      ),
    ),
  ),
)
```

The desired output that I'm unsure of how to do is:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'key' => 'Company 1',
    'values' => 
    array (
      0 => 
      array (
        'x' => 1,
        'y' => 25000000,
      ),
    ),
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'key' => 'Company 2',
    'values' => 
    array (
      0 => 
      array (
        'x' => 1,
        'y' => 25000000,
      ),      
    ),
  ),
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's only creating one array because you're pushing onto `$finance[0]` each time through the loop, rather than onto `$finance` itself. You're setting the `$companNname` variable, but not putting it anywhere in the array.

```
$finance = array();
for ($i = 1; $i <= $teamcount; $i++) {
    $finance[] = array(
        'key' => 'Company ' . $i,
        'values' => array(
            array('x' => 1, 'y' => 2500000)
        )
    );
}

$insertdata['finance'] = $finance;
```

Comment: Yep now that I see it that's pretty easy. Thanks for the help.

Comment: there was a small issue, the `;` after the `$i` on the Company name line causes an issue, should be an `,`.